# Add code highlighting options to the code menu

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Every time I have a question on how to color my code, I have to google the page for the highlighting rules.

Wouldn't it be more convenient to put the information into the code menu of the text editor, or include a link?

Comment: Bookmark the syntax highlighting rules page? :P

Comment: Alternatively, go there directly from the post editor window by clicking on the (?) button on the right of the toolbar and clicking on the [advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link that displays on the resulting menu bar. :P

Comment: Can you include which page you actually Google for? Because *color my code* can have different meanings, at least in my mind.